# Birds singing and dancing on telephone wire

Tags: birds, uk, bird-behaviour

Location: UK East Midlands, suburban garden. Bird: possible marsh tits, something in that size range with a black cap. Time: late July.

Two similar-looking birds were observed making high-pitched, very loud calls while "dancing" (wobbling from side to side) perched on a telephone/telegraph wire. If disturbed they would move to another wire and carry on as before.

I have a few related questions. First off, is this courting behaviour? And if so, why are these birds courting when small British bird species do not nest after July?

Second, is this kind of shaking "dance" and call combo diagnostic for a particular species?

Comment: Welcome Andy! Do you have pictures? What colors are they, and do they have the same colors and markings? Genders often have differences, which indicate a mated pair. They may be watching over young on the ground, and teaching them to fly. Is the screeching related to presence of other birds?   Wire sitting is common. If it's new for these birds, has their environment changed, like removal of trees or plants? Are these migrants? When do they usually go? Where exactly do you live? Can you give us more details like this, and anything else you can think of? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Coming to this late, but this is typical behaviour for the [Long-tailed Tit](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/long-tailed-tit/).

These birds are almost always seen in groups and stay very close together.  They roost and perch on wires or thin branches, staying very close together.

You talk of a black cap.  Long-tailed tits have black markings on their heads but with a white centre.